# Manhwa that starts off with a guy who had long, shaggy hair and scars all over him, stuck in a cave

Tags: story-identification, manga

So I remember reading this book a couple years ago on Mangaowl, but the site got taken down and there was this one book that I remember and I'm trying to find it.

It started off with this guy who had long, shaggy hair, who was stuck in a cave and had scars all over him. What I remember most was his face being the worst, and he was extremely powerful, to the point that everyone was trying to get rid of him. Powerful in the way that he didn’t have to use weapons, he just used his hands and I think he did have some spell casting skills but I’m not sure. Then one day, he got his hair cut or he was revived with his hair cut, idk, but he didn't have any more scars on him and he was just as powerful as he was before the cave incident.

I also remember him having a friend who I think left him behind, but for a good cause, and they reunited or whatever and all was good. I also remember the main character being able to develop new levels by either beating people up or killing a creature made by the government or whatever.

And there was another instance where the main character and his reunited friend went to other houses and took down items found in the house, such as masks or a statue of a horse, and found out that they were "souvenirs" given to the owner of the house by the government, and those "souvenirs" had cameras or something lodged in them.

Idk if that's enough info but that's about as far as I got.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You said this was a manhwa, so would I be correct in assuming this in full colour? Also, you said the main character was extremely powerful; can you be more specific? Could he cast spells, or project some type of energy, or was he just extremely strong? And did he use any weapons?

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Can you confirm that this isn't an isekai or VR story? i.e. nothing in the opening takes place in our world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *[The Return of the Disaster-Class Hero](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-return-of-the-disaster-class-hero)*.

> There once was the strongest Hero on earth. "But he died though. How does a guy we killed gonna come back?" "I know right. But if there was a way to come back, he would come back." But did he really come back after 20 years? "What are you so surprised about? Why. Did you do something to feel guilty about?" You bastards. I won't let you get away with it.

At the very start, the protagonist is the 13th of the 12 heroes, and is stronger than the rest of them combined despite not having god's blessing. The other 12 are jerks and generally try to extort money from the world's governments in exchange for fighting monsters that no weapon can damage. Shortly after the start of the story, they all go into a dungeon, and the main character is trapped in a cave-like area with hordes of monsters.

He's scarred from the start, and gets even worse while in the cave.

[image: Before cave] [image: After the cave]

After escaping from the cave by killing everything, he's back in the real world, and his body is immediately healed. Judging from the cover pictures, he eventually does get a haircut, but his face is fixed even before that.

[image: Outside the cave]

I haven't read enough to confirm anything about the government surveillance, new levels, or meeting the friend that left him behind, but I feel the scars and cave-like area are enough for identifying this.

Comment: YESSSS THANK YOU!!! 